# All the controls (ex. buttons, textboxes) don't appear the way I want on other PCs even after properly installing the softwares, VS 2019 C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, controls

All the controls appear displaced from the position I had set and sometimes even go out of the main form,
this problem is troubling me since long. I would appreciate if anyone helps.
I could also attach screenshots if you are having troubling understanding.
I had searched a lot for this problem but couldn't find any answers.

Comment: winforms? the question is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set AutoScaleMode property of the form None.

[image: AutoScaleModeSCSH]

[AutoScaleMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.autoscalemode?view=netframework-4.8)